# SaaS Domain Mapping: Cname to subdomain

Tags: virtualhost, cname-record, wildcard, saas, serveralias

I read a lot of threads here and I think I'm doing everything perfectly.

I setup a cname record on domain.com with the name www and the answer the.subdomain.com

However when I go to www.domain.com it shows the content on www.subdomain.com instead of the.subdomain.com

Any idea why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the zone file?

You should check if you add CNAME record of `domain.com` to `www.subdomain.com` not `the.subdomain.com`

e.g.

```
www    IN CNAME  www.subdomain.com
```

or

```
www    IN CNAME  subdomain.com
```

If you already write `the.subdomain.com`, it's probably `subdomain.com` use wildcard to handle all subdomains which resolve to the same IP as the root domain.

If that's the case, `domain.com` will resolve to `subdomain.com` instead of `the.subdomain.com`. You need to configure the web server as the CNAME record will not cause a redirect.